# How to clear a MultipartFormDataContent in C# xamarin forms android?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I'm working with C# xamarin forms android and I'm trying to ***remove*** the items that are inside of my **MultipartFormDataContent** but I can't do it. I've tried these codes:

Using null when I try to upload again the MultipartFormDataContent it gives me the error "System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

```
content = null;
```

Also i've tried Dispose() but it gaves me this error when I try to upload again "System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.":

```
content.Dispose();
```

But It doesn't let me clean my MultipartFormDataContent.

this is my code:

```
    MultipartFormDataContent content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
    List<StreamContent> listStreamContent = new List<StreamContent>();
    private async void sendImages()
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < listStreamContent.Count; x++)
        {
           content.Add(listStreamContent[x], "file", listFullPathImg[x]);
        }
        var httpClient = new HttpClient();
        var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(url, content);
        string res = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        await DisplayAlert("Result", res, "okey");
        for (int x = 0; x < listFullPathImg.Count; x++)
        {
           File.Delete(listFullPathImg[x]);
        }
        clearMultipartFormDataContent();
    }

    public void clearMultipartFormDataContent()
    {
        try
        {
            listStreamContent.Clear();
            content.Dispose();

            //content = null;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // handler exception
        }
    }
```

---

I know that for example, with a list like this

```
List<string> listImgName = new List<string>();
```

I can do something like this and it clean my list:

```
listImgName.Clear();
```

How could I do something like that but with a MultipartFormDataContent ?

Thank you very much!

Comment: You can't.  If you are only using `content` inside this one method, there is no need to declare it as a class variable.  Just declare it local to the method and it will fall out of scope when the method exits.

Comment: Thank you! It worked perfectly. I will put my code below. Maybe it helps someone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

I **cannot clean** my **MultipartFormDataContent** but I can declare it inside of my function. And  that way it destroyed itself and I can use it again. So I did this and it worked. I left my code here:

```
List<StreamContent> listStreamContent = new List<StreamContent>();
private async void sendImages()
{
    MultipartFormDataContent content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
    for (int x = 0; x < listStreamContent.Count; x++)
    {
       content.Add(listStreamContent[x], "file", listFullPathImg[x]);
    }
    var httpClient = new HttpClient();
    var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(url, content);
    string res = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    await DisplayAlert("Result", res, "okey");
    for (int x = 0; x < listFullPathImg.Count; x++)
    {
       File.Delete(listFullPathImg[x]);
    }
    listStreamContent.Clear();
}
```